# Transforming Text To Vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, text-processing, information-retrieval

I have a dictionary having words and the frequency of each words.

```
{'cxampphtdocsemployeesphp': 1,
'emptiness': 1, 
'encodingundefinedconversionerror': 1, 
'msbuildexe': 2,
'e5': 1, 
'lnk4049': 1,
'specifierqualifierlist': 2, .... }
```

Now I want to create a bag of words model using this dictionary( I don't want to use standard library and function. I want to apply this using the algorithm.)

1. Find N most popular words in the dictionary and numerate them. Now we have a dictionary of the most popular words.
2. For each title in the dictionary create a zero vector with the dimension equals to N.
3. For each text in the corpora iterate over words which are in the dictionary and increase by 1 the corresponding coordinate.

I have my text which I will use to create the vector using a function.

The function would look like this,

```
def my_bag_of_words(text, words_to_index, dict_size):
"""
    text: a string
    dict_size: size of the dictionary

    return a vector which is a bag-of-words representation of 'text'
"""


 Let say we have N = 4 and the list of the most popular words is 

['hi', 'you', 'me', 'are']

Then we need to numerate them, for example, like this: 

{'hi': 0, 'you': 1, 'me': 2, 'are': 3}

And we have the text, which we want to transform to the vector:
'hi how are you'

For this text we create a corresponding zero vector 
[0, 0, 0, 0]

And iterate over all words, and if the word is in the dictionary, we increase the value of the corresponding position in the vector:
'hi':  [1, 0, 0, 0]
'how': [1, 0, 0, 0] # word 'how' is not in our dictionary
'are': [1, 0, 0, 1]
'you': [1, 1, 0, 1]

The resulting vector will be 
[1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Any help in applying this would be really helpful. I am using python for implementation.

Thanks,

Neel

Comment: Please provide the example output for your input. (What would my_bag_of_words return, exactly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first calculate corpus frequency for each term, for your case for each word and keep them in a *frequency dictionary*. Let's say cherry happens to occur 78 times in your corpus **cheery --> 78** you need to keep. Then sort your frequency dictionary descending by frequency values, then keep first N pairs.

Then, for your enumeration you may keep a dictionary as an index. For instance, **cherry --> term2** for *index dictionary*.

Now, an incidence matrix needed to be prepared. It will be vectors of documents, like this:

```
doc_id   term1 term2 term3 .... termN
doc1       35     0    23         1
doc2        0     0    13         2
   .        .     .     .         .
docM        3     1     2         0
```

Each document(text, title, sentence) in your corpus needs to have an id or index as well as listed above. It is time to create a vector for a document. Iterate through your documents and get terms by tokenizing them, you have tokens per document. Iterate through tokens, check if next token exists in your *frequency dictionary*. If true, update your zero vector by using your *index dictionary* and *frequency dictionary*.

Let's say doc5 has cherry and we have it in our first N popular terms. Get its frequency (it was 78) and index (it was term5). Now update zero vector of doc5:

```
doc_id   term1 term2 term3 .... termN
doc1       35     0    23         1
doc2        0     0    13         2
   .        .     .     .         .
doc5        0    78     0         0 (under process)
```

You need to do this for each token against all popular terms for every document in your corpus.

At the end you will end up with a NxM matrix, which contains vectors of M documents in your corpus.

I can suggest you to look at IR-Book. https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html

You may think using a tf-idf based matrix instead of corpus frequency-based term incidence matrix as they propose as well.

Hope this post helps,

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I did the research from my end and would like to share my answer as well!

My data which looks something like this has been stored in a list:

```
data_list = ['draw stacked dotplot r',
 'mysql select records datetime field less specified value',
 'terminate windows phone 81 app',
 'get current time specific country via jquery',
 'configuring tomcat use ssl',...]
```

Going forward I calculated the frequency of each word in my list,

```
words_counts = {}                                                      
for text in data_list:
   for word in text.split():
      if word in words_counts:
        words_counts[word] += 1
      else:
        words_counts[word] = 1
```

As a result of this my words_counts dictionary will have all the words in my data_list and their frequency.
It will look something like this

```
 {'detailed': 6,
 'ole_handle': 1,
 'startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges': 2,
 'pccf02102': 1,
 'insight': 2,
 'combinations': 26,
 'tuplel': 1}
```

Now for our my_bag_of_word function, I need sort my words_counts dictionary in descending order and assign the index for each word.

```
index_to_word = sorted(words_counts.key(), key = lambda x:words_counts[x], reverse = True) 
words_to_index = {word:i for i,word in enimerate(index_to_words)}
```

Now our words_to_index would look something like this:

```
  {'address': 387,
 'behind': 706,
 'page': 23,
 'inherited': 1617,
 '106': 4677,
 'posting': 1293,
 'expressions': 876,
 'occured': 3241,
 'highest': 2989}
```

Now finally we can get the vector of our text using the dictionary we have created,

```
def my_bag_of_words(text, words_to_index, size_of_dictionary):
   word_vector = np.zeros(size_of_dictionary)
   for word in text.split():
       if word in words_to_index:
          word_vector[words_to_index[word]] += 1
   return word_vector
```

This was really a nice way to learn and understand the concept. Thnaks folks for your help and support.

Happy Learning

Neel

Comment: Congratulations and thank you for sharing your experience, effort and solution from your end.

Comment: @berkin Thanks for your answer as well. Happy Learning!